# Finding the source of a wave based on its curvature

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

If you had a perfectly still pool of water and dipped your finger in it, the disturbance would cause waves to ripple through the water, away from you finger. If you measured how curved the waves are, could you find the distance from the measuring point to where the waves started? If this is possible, could you do the same with electromagnetic waves?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, and a variant of it is even done quite often!

A [monopulse radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopulse_radar) is a clever radar which uses the difference between two signals to provide an azimuth and elevation towards an emitter of an EM wave (in the case of radar, this emitted wave is an echo of a signal emitted by the radar).  If you have two monopulse radars in different positions, you can triangulate the position of the source.  Doing so would be the equivalent of taking 4 measurements (2 per radar) of the curvature.

Comment: thanks! do you have any additional details as to how the curvature is measured? i assumed youd need three points of measurement per beam.

Comment: @tau 3 would be a minimum, but the easiest to demonstrate approach involves 2 mono pulse antennas, each of which has 2 antennas at different positions.  If you read the Wikipedia article, it shows how a monopulse radar turns the returns from 2 antennae into a direction (it's not something that fits in a stack exchange comment).  2 radars could then use their directions to triangulate the source.